# Accessing value from a JavaScript function and using it in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to access the returned value from my JavaScript function to be used to change the color of the body's background in CSS.

Not quite sure how to properly do this, here is what I was trying to do but I guess it's not that simple...

```
<script>
function changeColor(){
    var randomColorHex;
    randomColorHex ='#'+ (Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
    return randomColorHex;
}
</script>

<body style="background-color:<script>changeColor()</script>"
```

All help is much appreciated.

Comment: A CSS hash color has to have 3 or 6 hex digits.  The random number you generate probably will not.

Comment: You should probably read about the DOM and how to manipulate it using javascript.

Answer (score 4):

Set it like so...

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = changeColor();
```

You may want to then change your function's name to `getRandomColor()`.

Also, you want to generally avoid inline styles in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Use your current function, and use javascript to add this to your body, inline styles generally aren't the best practice :)

As Alex pointed out, I'd change the name of your function to something a bit more useful.

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
```

**DEMO:** `http://jsfiddle.net/shannonhochkins/L3D2R/`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot insert the result of a JavaScript function inside of a style.. HTML/CSS/JS just doesn't operate that way.  HOWEVER....

Personally, I would recommend using a script library like jQuery (jquery.com).  Include the jQuery script on your page (before other scripts).  Use a script like:

```
function changeColor(element) {
    var randomColorHex;
    randomColorHex ='#'+ (Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
    // element, by here is a jQuery object, the .css() method allows
    // us to change styles on html elements
    element.css("background-color", randomColorHex);
}

// we put a function inside the $ function (the jQuery function)
// jQuery calls the function when the page is ready to process elements in the DOM
$(function() {
  // call your function - here we pass a jQuery object, it select the "body" element
  // HOWEVER, you can put any CSS selector in the *$* function here and have it process
  // those elements
  changeColor($("body"));
});
```

This is just an example, but shows the power of jQuery

Answer (score 0):

May be you can modify your function a bit to accept the element and property:

```
function changeColor(element, property){
    var randomColorHex ='#'+ (Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
    element.style[property] = randomColorHex;
    return randomColorHex;
}
```

And call it like:

```
changeColor(document.body, 'backgroundColor');
changeColor(document.body, 'color');
```